# Prove that $\ f*g = f$

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, convolution, fast-fourier-transform

Good morning,

We have : $g \in$ $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $\forall p \in [0;\infty)$ and $f\in$ $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$,
$\widehat{f}(x) =0$  if $|x| \geq R $,
$\varphi = \widehat{g}$ such as  $\varphi(x) = 1, \left | x \right | \leqslant R $ and $  x \in  \mathbb{R}^n$, $\varphi\in {C_{c}^{\infty }(\mathbb {R} ^{n})}$

So I did a Fourier Transform of $\ f*g$ (Convolution product) and got $\widehat{f*g}(x)=\widehat{f}$
How can I say that $\ f*g = f$ with what I found ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What do you mean by "$\widehat{f(x)} =0$ if $|x|\ge R$"? Do you mean that "$\widehat{f}\color{red}{(x)} =0$ if $|x|\ge R $"?

Comment: Yes, I'm learning LaTeX...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier transform is injective (in the relevant function spaces).
If $\hat h=\hat f$, then $h=f$.
Now you have $h=f*g$.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: @AFrenchstudent I'm glad it helped! Please accept an answer when it settles your question. You also have enough reputation to vote up any questions and answers you like.

Comment: Just a supplement: A proof that Fourier Transform is injective on $L^1$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542451/injectivity-of-fourier-transform-between-l1-mathbbr-and-c-0-mathbbr).